# bar pointPlacement works bad in get one data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When using the `pointPlacement` in highcharts when data is more than 1 it works fine, but when get one data from server all bars compress to one bar.

Sorry my English is bad

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Seattle HQ',
      'San Francisco',
      'Tokyo'
    ]
  },
  yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Employees'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Profit (millions)'
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  legend: {
    shadow: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false,
      shadow: false,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Employees',
    color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
    data: [150],
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    pointPlacement: -0.2
  }, {
    name: 'Employees Optimized',
    color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
    data: [140],
    pointPadding: 0.4,
    pointPlacement: -0.2
  }, {
    name: 'Profit',
    color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
    data: [183.6],
    tooltip: {
      valuePrefix: '$',
      valueSuffix: ' M'
    },
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    pointPlacement: 0.2,
    yAxis: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Profit Optimized',
    color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
    data: [203.6],
    tooltip: {
      valuePrefix: '$',
      valueSuffix: ' M'
    },
    pointPadding: 0.4,
    pointPlacement: 0.2,
    yAxis: 1
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 360px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[you can try my code here](https://codepen.io/miladmodaresi/pen/QWWpdPz)

[try the normal code](https://codepen.io/miladmodaresi/pen/gOOmmMj?&editable=true)

Comment: Please, post your code on the question, not only in an external link.

Comment: i'm sorry. my English is not good and it's hard for me to balance between code and details

Comment: I believe in you, try harder please. Just place the code in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Highcharts bug reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11800

As a workaround you can set `pointRange: 1`:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointRange: 1,
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lzx3shrn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange